# What's Wrong with my code and any suggestion to improve it

Tags: python

```
wight = input("What is your wight ? ")
wight = int(wight)
Unit = input("(L) for pounds and (K) for Kilogram :")

Unit = Unit.upper()

while Unit != "L" or "K":
    Unit = input("(L) for pounds and (K) for Kilogram are the only valide charechtar:")
if Unit == "L" :
    Newwight = wight / 2.2 
    print(f"You are {wight} Pound that is equal to {Newwight} Kilogram")
elif Unit == "K" :
    Newwight = wight * 2.2 
    print(f"You are {wight} Kilogram that is equal to {Newwight} Pounds")
        
print("the End")
```

when I run it
the terminal display the phrase (L) for pounds and (K) for Kilogram are the only valide charechtar:

again and again

Comment: Your indentation seems to be wrong. You probably meant for the if's to be inside the loop. Also, `Unit != "L" or "K"` doesn't do what you expect. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Comment: `Unit != "L" or "K"` (`or "K"`) - is always `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while Unit != "L" or "K"
```

does not check if Unit is equal 'L' or 'K'. It check if `Unit` is not equal to 'L' or if 'K'. And 'K' (like any character, non empty string, integer not equal to 0, ..) is a so called truthy value that gets evaluated to True. So no matter what you input, you always get a True value and the while-loop continues.

You have to check

```
while Unit != "L" and Unit != "K"
```

or alternatively

```
while not (Unit == "L" or Unit == "K")
```

which is logically the same.

Comment: Or more succinctly :`while Unit not in "LK":`

Comment: @user19077881 no, either `while unit not in set('LK')` or you allow literal `"LK"` input.